# How to PUT a JSON array of objects in Swagger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

Currently using Swagger.io to document my API. Trying to understand how to document sending a custom json object.

- PUT on a collection to /some_endpoint
- MIME: application/json
- Custom Data:

  ```
  [
    {"keyA": "a value", "keyB": "b value"},
    {"keyA": "a value", "keyB": "b value"}
  ]
  ```

Is it possible to document this in Swagger?

```
/some_endpoint:
    put:
      description: |
        desc goes here
      parameters:
        - name: guid
          in: query
          description:
          required: true
          type: string
          format: string          
      # Expected responses for this operation
      responses:
        # Response code
        200:
          description: Successful response
```

Comment: Are `keyA` and `keyB` fixed property names or is that a map with arbitrary key names?

Comment: @Helen It is Fixed property names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON data is sent in the request body, so it needs to be defined as a [body parameter](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameter-object). The body structure is described using the [`schema`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#schemaObject) keyword (not `type`). In your example the data is an array of objects, where each object has properties `keyA` and `keyB`.

```
paths:
  /some_endpoint:
    put:
      summary: Puts something
      description: |
        desc goes here
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          required: true
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/MyObject'
            # If you need to define array size constraints:
            minItems: 1
            minItems: 10

definitions:
  MyObject:
    type: object
    properties:
      keyA:
        type: string
      keyB:
        type: string
    # If keyA and keyB are required:
    required:
      - keyA
      - keyB
```

To specify that the request data is JSON, use the `consumes` key at the operation level. If all of your API operations consume JSON, you can add `consumes` at the root level of the spec instead.